# What does GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2" mean?

Tags: debian, grub2, debian-stretch

One of our [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-servers won't boot into the newest installed kernel, and during troubleshooting I came across this:

```
grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
```

Output:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

I haven't seen this syntax before. What does this mean?

Comment: Slightly related (though it is not about sub menus): *[How can I change the default boot menu option from the GRUB command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340168/how-can-i-change-the-default-boot-menu-option-from-the-grub-command-line/1588301#1588301)* (answers are about setting the top level GRUB menu default)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From **[GNU GRUB Manual 2.02: default](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/default.html#default)**:

> If the entry is in a submenu, then it must be identified using the
>   number, title, or id of each of the submenus starting from the top
>   level, followed by the number, title, or id of the menu entry itself,
>   with each element separated by ‘>’

Meaning that

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
```

Represents the following logic:
If entry `1` is a submenu, open it and select entry `2` from there.

Which is most likely the advanced submenu leading to a fallback/backup/recovery kernel.

Comment: +1. Additionally you can also validate the selection `2` in above example, what it points to, from command line, by looking at the grub menu-options configuration - `sudo grub-mkconfig | grep -iE "menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux" | awk '{print i++ " : "$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'`     [4 more details : https://askubuntu.com/a/1393019/350255]

Answer (score 3):

Take note that for syntax like "1>2", the index starts from 0. So if the 3rd item is a submenu inside which the 2nd item is the default you want to boot, then it should be "2>1".

Comment: Also take note that the double quotes are required (unlike for the top level; `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` for the second (top level) menu item will work (without the double quotes)).